# How can i find sum(field1) from all table in mysql database

Tags: mysql

I try sum price in a sell table, 
but sell table split monthly

ex:

1. sell_14_01
2. sell_14_02
3. sell_14_03
4. ...
5. sell_15_01

I try find sum price all sell table use one sql query

I find all tablename using the that query

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_schema = 'mydb' and TABLE_NAME like 'sell_%'
```

but I cant

```
select sum(price) from (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_schema = 'mydb' and TABLE_NAME like 'sell_%')
```

***** I cant php or other programing language, only mysql query

can you help me pls

Comment: I don't think this is actually possible. Tables are not really designed to be used dynamically.

Comment: Build a view which contains all tables (UNION ALL) then query that view. When you create a new table, you have to maintain the view to include the new table. Another option is to use dynamic query.

Comment: How can I use dynamic query. can you write an example for me